# Meteor MongoDb connection on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to run meteor application on Windows.

```
meteor --settings settings.json --port 3000
```

I am getting this error:

```
λ meteor --settings settings.json --port 3000
[[[[[ C:\Users\User\code\some_service ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160518-08:35:40.664(2)? (STDERR)
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
W20160518-08:35:40.665(2)? (STDERR)     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:27)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:102:40)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
W20160518-08:35:40.666(2)? (STDERR)     at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.4.43\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:74)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.4.43\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
W20160518-08:35:40.667(2)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
W20160518-08:35:40.668(2)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.4.43\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
W20160518-08:35:40.668(2)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20160518-08:35:40.668(2)? (STDERR)     at net.js:441:14
W20160518-08:35:40.668(2)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
```

from the stack trace I concluded that it can not establish connection to mongo db. I have investigated a bit and they say out there that I should downgrade from mongo 3.2 to 3.0 because 3.2 is not compatible.

If this is a problem. How do I change mongo version in meteor.

If the problem is something else please advise.

I am using METEOR@1.3.2.4 and node v0.10.43. The application works fine on mac and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution using Windows Server 2012 R2 instead of Windows 10 previously. With no other changes I just tried the sam thing on the server and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you should downgrade your mongo installation to 3.0
Your problem will be fixed.

Comment: How can I do that on windows? Thanks.

Comment: There is a full documentation about that :) . You can found it here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-downgrade/